# Jquery Select 2 Hang the browser

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

```
$("#pick, #drop").select2({
    createSearchChoice: function (term, data) {
        if ($(data).filter(function() {
            return this.text.localeCompare(term) === 0;
        }).length === 0) {
            return {
                id:term, text:term
            };
        }
    },
    multiple: false,
    data: [ 
        {id:'ZMH', text: 'ZMH, 108 Mile Ranch, Canada'},
        {id:'AAH', text: 'AAH, Aachen, Germany'},    
        //and thousands others airpots.
    ] 
});
```

Due to the data volumne firefox hangs with select2, Can anyone suggest me other way to use the feature with no hang to work smoothly. For example how can i use an xml to populate the data or any other option.

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/F574g/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to minify your search result

use matcher.

Example

```
$("#pick,#drop").select2({
    matcher: function(term, text,option) {
            return option.html().toUpperCase().indexOf(term.toUpperCase())==0; 
        },
    sortResults: function(results, container, query){
        if(query.term == ""){
            return results.slice(0,50);
        }else{
            return results;
        }
    },
        //... other setting
});
```

For example

data result => [india,mumbai,australia,sydney]

When I type i

=>result without matcher

india, mumbai,australia

=>result with matcher

india

> > use of matcher because to search australia I am not going to type i so by removing unwanted result you can stop your select2 from hanging

Note : also try sortResults

**EDITED CODE**

```
$("#pick,#drop").select2({
    multiple: false,
    query: function (query) {
        var data = {results: []};
        if(query.term == ""){
            for(var i = 0; i < 20 ;i++){
                data.results.push({id: keyword[i].id, text: keyword[i].text});
            }
        }else{
            for(var obj in keyword){
                if(keyword[obj].text.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.term.toLowerCase()) == 0){
                    data.results.push({id: keyword[obj].id, text: keyword[obj].text});
                }
            }
        }
            query.callback(data);
        }

});
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/F574g/2/)**

Comment: Still hang with 10000 records.

Comment: Actually the problem is loading the large record set at the load time.  So this won't work.

Comment: @user1610100 can you fiddle out

Comment: This is not hanging now, but not searching for relevant result.

Comment: Rajesh, I will fiddle this and add the URI here in a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned you've a large dataset, *don't load all the records at the same time.*

Instead try to make use of **`scrolling`**, 10/15 per each scroll.

Ahh I got a similar issue that is being tracked in Git, where a person(named *rocanowi*) recommend infinite scroll approach

> For a large data sets, I think it's better not to load all data on
>   page load. If you use database, you better use the "Loading Remote
>   Data" example and return it 10 data (for example) at a time. *Or you
>   can use the "Infinite Scroll with Remote Data" example for more data
>   load per search.*